# Don't see last app version in android Flurry

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

i have a problem with flurry for android. I don't see last app version in filter several days (about 5 days). Later new version got to version list in filter very fast.

Also if check "TOP 10 VERSIONS BY ACTIVE USERS" i can suppose that my new version is saved as other. I upload new version 20 march and on graph i see that version other grow from 20 march.

I use SDK version 6.6.0. Now i upgraded to 6.9.2. Later flurry determined version of app without problem.

For init flurry i use the following code:

```
new FlurryAgent.Builder()
                .withLogEnabled(true)
                .withListener(getFlurryAgentListener())
                .build(context, MY_API_KEY);
```

Can anyone say what i do wrong or how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app has more than 1000 app versions.

To correct this you will need to delete some older versions you no longer need.

Currently this can only be done in the old 'Flurry Classic' site. See here:

[image: Flurry version management]

We will be adding this feature to the new Flurry site soon.

Finally you can avoid problems with the version limit by using separate project api keys for development/testing versus the published version of the app.

Comment: Thanks! Can i switch from new to classic site? and how i can to do it?

Comment: I sent a link to you in your support ticket